# FindRegionTransform again

Tags: functions, bugs, regions, geometric-transform

**Bug introduced in 13.0.0** [CASE:4895492] [CASE:4895697]

---

Studying a new command of version 13.0.0 `FindRegionTransform`, I execute an example from the documentation:

```
p = CirclePoints[10.];SeedRandom[1234]; q = RandomPoint[Circle[], 10];
ListPlot[{p, q}]
```

[image]

It is clear there is no affine transform which maps `p` onto `q`. However,  `tr = FindRegionTransform[p, q]` results in $$\text{TransformationFunction}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.000753395 & -2.4118 & 1.29419 \\
 0.0265124 & 2.75065 & -2.58762 \\
 0. & 0. & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)\right] .$$

The question arises: what does `tr` do?

Comment: It's essentially a rotation matrix RotationMatrix[θ] augmented with another row and column that do nothing because z is zero in the 2d case. Look at ArcCos[0.000753395] giving approx pi/2, ArcCos[2.75065] gives zero + some imaginary part, -ArcSin[-2.4118] gives approx pi/2 + imaginary part for example.

Comment: ^ although if you look at `Graphics[{Red, Point[p], Blue, Point[q], Black,Arrow[{#, tr[#]}] &/@ p }]` which shows arrows from p to the transformed points, it's not quite as simple as I realized and appears to transform some points way outside the circle.

Comment: @flinty:Therefore, we deal with a bug. The documentation says `tr[p]` should be equal to `q`.

Comment: The report has been submitted ( [CASE:4895492] ).

Comment: @user64494, take a look at the documentation for [``FindRegionTransform``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRegionTransform.html), Scope > Basic Uses > 2nd Example. Isn't this the same case as yours? Therefore, it might not be a bug, but an (undocumented) feature? :-)

Comment: @Domen My *Mathematica* 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64 [prints errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e93Oi.png) when evaluating the second example under Scope > Basic Uses. Do you get errors messages too?

Comment: Also, it doesn't evaluate the third example: `FindRegionTransform[Interval[], Line[{{1}, {0}}]]`, `FindRegionTransform[Cuboid[], Cube[]]` and `FindRegionTransform[Ball[5], Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]` are left unevaluated. Do you observe this too?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: I obtain a warning "RegionEmbeddingDimension::reg: -0.951057 is not a correctly specified region." and the output.

Comment: Many examples from the Docs page do not evaluate...

Comment: Unevaluated examples reported as [CASE:4895697].